c# - IReadOnlyList accepts implementation of return type as return value, IReadOnlyDictionary doesn't
public IReadOnlyList<IA> Foo => new List<A>(); //works
public IReadOnlyDictionary<Guid, IA> Foo2 => new Dictionary<Guid, A>(); //throws CS0266

public class A : IA
{
}

public interface IA
{
}

Stumbled across this, does anybody know why a property/method doesn't accept a Dictionary of a type implementing the interface of the return-type as return-value?

read about co-variance and contra-variance in c#

See the update in this question which explains why IReadOnlyDictionary is not covariant.

In short, it's because of covariance. For the IReadOnlyCollection<out T> the T is covariant (see out keyword in the declaration). So, you can downcast from implementation to interface here.
For the IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey,TValue> there is no co- or contrvariance specified, so you can only use the exact type here.
